# "sticky" cursor along a path in paperjs

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'd like to be able to drag the mouse along a pre-defined path in `paperjs` and have a "sticky" circle mark roughly where my mouse is along that path, with the center of the circle sitting **on** the path.

I've managed to get [pretty close](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/nZOxboMwEIZf5cQSUBGFSCxEdMnUIVKldiMMhlwSC8eObEMHxLvXMUljpCIlRUKYu/vvPv+Y3uPkhF7mfTao66MXerXYXd4BOiLhTPQRcuD4DR9m6QerrdxysPFIaSkaXAsmpKlZVIzUzcItOIkOv4RfpHGYxuVEyyi3qSSOQ3PPJF3hmL9A1a1UQq6prBk6cNEY8XtJdrRVGaThqHnkcvaSXbbS4uIJdUcVrRhmsCdM4eAC71teayo4CL4RrcKN8cTHDrkOoL9NcHcUnYWiVpGDrTMByrXTcnTBxFAqtM2VqbXOHVC/u3Hf7XzzGIDuwZ/oI4b8YD71Ww5Lh2uebCov4nKkhJcpV5FcE8HrcjXT9Wqeaapli79VA6Dxch41zyF5CPVv0v/RzI27q+wJuMvGhX2Yf6uSSBo7XnlZUQ4/) - the following does exactly what I want for straight lines, but it doesn't work near kinks and the center of the circle "comes off" from the line:

```
var path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.moveTo([50,50]);
path.lineTo([100,100]);
path.lineTo([150,50]);

var cursorCircle = new Path.Circle({radius: 5,
                                    strokeColor: 'blue',
                                    visible: false});

function onMouseMove(event) {
  cursorCircle.position = event.point;

  var intersections = path.getIntersections(cursorCircle);
  if (intersections.length >= 2) {
    cursorCircle.position = (intersections[0].point + intersections[1].point)/2;
    cursorCircle.visible = true;
  } else if (intersections.length == 1) {
    cursorCircle.position = intersections[0].point;
    cursorCircle.visible = true;
  } else {
    cursorCircle.visible = false;
  }
}
```

How can I keep the circle on the line at all times (assuming the cursor is close enough)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the [reference](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getnearestpoint-point):

```
var star = new Path.Star({
    center: view.center,
    points: 10,
    radius1: 30,
    radius2: 60,
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

var circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 3,
    fillColor: 'red'
});

function onMouseMove(event) {
    // Get the nearest point from the mouse position
    // to the star shaped path:
    var nearestPoint = star.getNearestPoint(event.point);

    // Move the red circle to the nearest point:
    circle.position = nearestPoint;
}
```